Projection into a Hilbert space with respect to an orthonormal sequence.
Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and let $(e_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal sequence in $H$. We define $$V:=\overline{\text{span}(e_k)}$$ I must prove that for all $x\in H$ the projection onto $V$ it is the following $$P_V(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\langle x, e_k\rangle e_k.$$
Here are the steps I followed.
First step. I prove that for all $x\in H$ the vector $$y=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle x, e_k\rangle e_k$$ exists in $H$ and $x-y$ is orthogonal to every $e_k$, thus $(x-y)\in (\text{span}(e_k))^\perp$
Second step. I prove that $$x\in \overline{\text{span}(e_k)}\iff x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle x, e_k\rangle e_k$$
Then I deduce that $y\in \overline{\text{span}(e_k)}$
Third step I observe that $$\left(\overline{\text{span}(e_k)}\right)^\perp=(\text{span}(e_k))^\perp$$
Then results that for all $x\in H$ $$x=y+(x-y),$$ where $y\in \overline{\text{span}(e_k)}$ and $(x-y)\in \left(\overline{\text{span}(e_k)}\right)^\perp$.
Since $\overline{\text{span}(e_k)}$ is a closed subspace of $H$ for the uniqueness of decomposition we have that $$P_V(x)=y$$ and we have done.

It's correct? Is there another way to look at this? I'm not sure in the second step tha why $y\in \overline{\text{span}(e_k)}$.


$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k \in span (e_i)$ so $y=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k \in \overline {span (e_i)}$

@geetha290krmYou might consider whether what I write is correct, to see if I understood your statement: $\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x, e_k\rangle e_k\in span(e_1,\dots, e_n)$, then $y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x, e_k\rangle e_k\in \overline{span(e_1,\dots, e_n)}\subseteq \overline{span(e_1, e_2, \dots)}$

No, you have to delete $\overline {span {e_1,e_2,...,e_n}}$ from your argument.

@geetha290krmYes, You are right. Just observe that $\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k\in span(e_1,e_2,\dots)$
